# SelectList with tiered optgroups?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I did some searching but wasn't able to find a post that matched what I was looking for.

I currently have a `SelectList` with the following structure:

Code:

```
<optgroup1>
   <Question1>
   <Question2>
   <Question3>
   <Question4>
<optgroup1>
<optgroup2>
   <Question1>
   <Question2>
   <Question3>
   <Question4>
<optgroup2>
```

Now, I am trying to split the questions into optgroups of their own so that the format is more like this:

Code 2:

```
<optgroup1>
    <subgroup1>
       <Question1>
       <Question2>
    <subgroup1>
    <subgroup2>
       <Question3>
       <Question4>
    <subgroup2>
<optgroup1>
<optgroup2>
   <subgroup3>
       <Question1>
       <Question2>
   <subgroup3>
   <subgroup4>
       <Question3>
       <Question4>
   <subgroup4>
<optgroup2>
```

Is it possible to create a tiered `SelectList` like *Code 2*? The trouble I'm running into is that when I create the list of questions as `SelectListItems`, I set the `Text`, `Value`, and the `Group` as a `SelectListGroup`. This is working to create a `SelectList` like the one in my first example, but I am having difficult wrapping my head around/knowing if it's possible to use multiple tiered `SelectListGroups` and how to approach this.

Comment: How is this related to LINQ?

Comment: I use LINQ to iterate over the list of questions and create each SelectListItem. Sorry if I didn't use the tag properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I have found that nested optgroups are still not supported. I will have to search for alternatives.